# Can I send HTTP request using lua scripting in redis?

Tags: redis, lua, stackexchange.redis

I have a scenario where, when a key which is set in redis reaches a certain count say n, I need to send a HTTP post request, is this possible using Lua scripting in redis?

Any help regarding this or alternate method to do this is appreciated.

PS: I have just stared using Redis please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't, Lua is running in a sandbox.
You should check the Redis Module [RedisGears](https://redisgears.io).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I had a look at RedisGears it will definitely help me. I need to do more reading on this.